# want to select all the descendant nodes in xml linq c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have following xml and trying to select all nodes inside the room node problem is that names of nodes inside the room node are almost random, therefore impossible to predict.

```
<room>
<info>1</info>
<something_here>1</something_here>
<something_else_here>no</something_else_here>
<something_else_here>no</something_else_here>
<something_else>no</something_else>
<attempt>no</attempt>
<date>09/03/2017</date>
<room_name>4.23</room_name>
```

I have tried this, but it´s returning all the descendant node room info as one string, and I want to that info to be separated by strings

```
tabela = xdoc.Descendants("room")
            .Where(i => (string)i.Element("attempt") == Convert.ToString("no"))
           .Select(element => element.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: `i.Element("attempt").Value`

Comment: `i.Element("attempt").Value` will return error if element is not found in xml  (null), while  `(string)i.Element("attempt")` will not return the error

Comment: you need to check if element is not null

Comment: still not working. it returns 11nononono09/03/20174.23 as one string and I want at least separated them by comma 1,1,no,no,no,no,09/03/2017,4.23 or in different strings for each value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating the list, it's important to run this `p.Element("attempt") != null` before you call this `p.Element("attempt").Value == "no"` so it does not throw an error if `p.Element("attempt")` does not exist.

```
XDocument thedoc = XDocument.Load(@"M:\StackOverflowQuestionsAndAnswers\XML_42699433\XML_42699433\file.xml");
List<string> theListOfValues = thedoc.Descendants("room")
.Where(p => p.Element("attempt") != null && p.Element("attempt").Value == "no")
.Elements()
.Select(p => p.Value).ToList();
string asLongString = string.Join(",", theListOfValues);
//make it the string you seem to be after
```

The `theListOfValues` contains only the values found within

Comment: Anytime. I'll add some comments and a `string.join()`